# Css not applying when include js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, infragistics

I am applying custom css to infrajistics webmonthcalendercontrol when I add custom day I apply css class which I define it on site.css, but when I include `contextmenu.js` file and some javascript function the css is not working,

```
.myUnavalable
{

    color:Green;
    background-color:Green;
    text-decoration:blink;
}
```

in contextmenu.js style for menu div is define.

```
    ContextMenuDiv.id = 'ContextMenu'; 
    ContextMenuDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    ContextMenuDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    ContextMenuDiv.style.border = '2px outset transparent';
    ContextMenuDiv.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
    ContextMenuDiv.style.textAlign = 'left';
    ContextMenuDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ContextMenuDiv.style.width = (Width + 11) + 'px';
```

I want to change background color of the `customdate`.
How to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you inspect the element in any kind of DOM Inspector (Firebug et. al.), do you see that the element in question has a. the class applied and b. its rules are not overwritten?

Comment: Use `!important` tag in your `css` files to make them over-ride all values set for style elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **firebug** and check which styles your control is taking. probably your `.js` file have its own css which overwrite your custom `css`.

if so,
try using `!important` in your `css`

eg.

```
.myUnavalable
{
    background-color:Green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question. Look at the code you posted.
Your class:

```
background-color:Green;
```

The javascript:

```
ContextMenuDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
```

The javascript is overwriting your style. Either remove the background color from the JS file or change your class to be this:

```
background-color:Green !important;
```

And take out the "Blink"... that's the UI equivalent of smacking your page viewer in the face with a rotten fish.